# KineticJS circles won't respond to clicks

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

```
//Sets up endgame and text variables for later use
var final = '';
var message = '';
var endGame = false;

//Ends the game by disabling input
function endGame(){
  feedButton.off('click');

  hydrateButton.off('click');

  sleepButton.off('click');

  entertainButton.off('click');

  startButton.off('click');
}
function gameStart(){
  healthDrop();
  sanityDrop();
  patienceDrop();
  difficult();
  randOne();
  randTwo();
  randThree();
  randFour();
  function indicateBegin(){
    imgk.setAttrs({fill: 'purple'});
  }
  function indicateOff(){
    imgk.setAttrs({fill: false});
  }
  var timer = setTimeout(indicateOff, 4000);
}

//Should ready KineticJS buttons for use
startButton.on('click', gameStart);
feedButton.on('click', tamaHibachi.feed);
hydrateButton.on('click', tamaHibachi.hydrate);
sleepButton.on('click', tamaHibachi.sleep);
entertainButton.on('click', tamaHibachi.entertain);
```

So, I've been trying to create a game in KineticJS for a class project, but I've found that none of my buttons work. I don't know if the problem lies in this part of the code, but I would believe it does. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Or post relevant parts of your kineticjs code?

Answer (score 0):

Without more info on your code it's hard to say anything. For instance, all my objects have 'ID's... container is a DIV with an id of 'container' so that you can then do this:

```
container.addEventListener('mousedown', startListening, false );
```

I can't tell from your code if you have all that set up right. It's probably nothing with Kinetic, because I have a huge project on the go with Kinetic and all the event listeners are working just fine.